# How to get selected rows count in DataGrip?

Tags: database, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I am new to DataGrip and I can't find a solution to this minor irk I have with it. Is there any way to get a count of all the rows I have selected or highlighted? For example, some other applications (Sequel Pro), display a count at the bottom in a status bar.

Comment: Check this answer right here [Datagrip - get row count (easily) on queries with more than 500 results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42343417/3211078)

Answer (score 0):

When selected, the character and lines will show on the bottom right corner of the screen. It will show in the format "255 char, 8 lines" depending on what is selected.

Comment: bottom right of my screen does not show that, just shows "2:1" , "n/a" , "n/a" an unlocked lock, and a man with a hat?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected or highlighted rows number from *Go To Row* widget in the bottom right corner:
[image: selection]

To get rows count for the selected table by clicking *Page Size* widget

[image: count]