# Datagrip - get row count (easily) on queries with more than 500 results

Tags: datagrip

Is there a way (setting or shortcut) for displaying the total row count of a query that outputs more than 500 rows - that is, without modifying the "Result set page size" value in preferences? I'm looking essentially for the output of `select count(*) from (<query>) t` in addition to the displayed rows.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Click on page-size of the result-set

[image: count(*) in DataGrip]

Comment: One more thing - would be nice if stripping out any "order by" clauses wasn't necessary for that method to work.

Comment: I agree that DataGrip should handle count even if the actual query has an order by clause. I currently get a message "[S1000][154] An ORDER BY clause is not allowed in a derived table."

Comment: I see there's an issue logged for this : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3315

Comment: Ok, but how do I change the default return to say 100,000?

Comment: Settings -> Datasbe -> data views -> Result Page Size. If you put -1, it  means ALL

Answer (score 14):

You can change it in settings:

1. File --> settings
2. Then in Database --> Data Views --> Uncheck Limit page size to 500

[image]

Comment: this loads all the data

Comment: You sir have saved me many extra minutes of work!! Thank you!!!!!! I generally use datagrip to export data so this saves me having to re query to get the whole dataset

Comment: but what would happen if resulting data is one billion rows big, for example - would it mean that it would have to load all of this data to my PC and crash because there's no RAM for that?

Answer (score 11):

Alternative to accepted answer (clicking to page-size), click the `Last Page` icon and it shows the count of items

[image]

Comment: In case you want more than 500 by default you can change it as described in here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207287649-Limit-the-number-of-rows-when-previewing-a-table-in-DataGrip

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question and not accepting it because I'm hoping there's a better way, but you can create a live template:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM ($SELECTION$) tablenameyoullneveruse
```

Select your query, then use ***Surround with Live Template...***

Still hoping for a simultaneous solution (not have to build 2nd query).

Answer (score 0):

Up-to-date info - now you need to press on the right part of page-size counter, where 501+ is in my example.

Сlicking left part of it now gives you choices to actually change the page size right there.

[image]